# Deformation Retractions of $X=\mathbb{R}^{3}-\{x\}-C_{1}-C_{2}$ and Homology Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

Consider a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and circles $C_{1}, C_{2} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$, where these three are all disjoint from each other. Then, consider the space $X=\mathbb{R}^{3}-\{x\}-C_{1}-C_{2}$. Compute the homology groups of $X$ using deformation retractions.

---

I've seen some solutions in the site for related problems that show that this would deformation retract to a wedge sum of some spaces, however I don't really see this. What would be a detailed explanation? (I'm kind of lost). Then, I think one would use Mayer-Vietoris sequences and cellular homology to compute the homology groups.

On a more general note, what would be a general "intuition" or method when deformation retracting a space to a simpler one for computations? I know the definitions, but not really a "method" or "algorithm" to use in order to simplify things (if that such thing exists in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

By applying homotopies, we may assume that $x$ is the origin $O$ and $C_1$ and $C_2$ are latitudes of the unit sphere.  Note that $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus\{O\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2$ via the map $y \mapsto \frac{y}{\|y\|}$.  Removing the circles from the sphere leaves us with the disjoint union of three connected pieces: the top and bottom "caps" are contractible, and the "ring" in the middle is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.

Comment: Thanks! How could one visualize $C_{1}, C_{2}$ as latitudes of the sphere though? After this, I think the homology groups would be trivial to compute (would they be $H_{1}=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_{0}=\mathbb{Z}^{3}$?). How would this generalize for the case where we have $\mathbb{R}^{3}-\{x\}-\{y\}-C_{1}-C_{2}$? (obviously the points and circles are still disjoint, I want to test my understanding). Would we use the fact that after removing a point from $S^{2}$ we get the solid disk in the plane? I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: You can apply homotopies to ensure that the circles lie on the unit sphere.  For instance, we could take them to be given by $z = \pm 1/2$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 3/4$.  Then projecting as above fixes them.

Comment: You have the right idea for your new question: $$\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{x\} \setminus \{y\} \simeq S^2 \setminus \{y\} \simeq \ \text{an open disc.}$$  Now cut out the circles: what does this leave?